# Creating multiple jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a ASP.NET MVC page which creates divs dynamically within an existing jQUery tab.

The parent tabs are coming fine but for some reason subtabs aren't gettiing created.

My Razor code is like this:

```
<div id="mainView">
    <ul class="mainMenu">
    @foreach(var myView in mainView.Childs)
    {
       <li><a href="#@(myView.Name)">@myView.Name</a></li>
    }
    </ul>
    @foreach(var myView in mainView.Childs)
    {
        if(myView.HasChilds)
        {
            <div id="@myView.Name" class="subView">
                <ul class="subMenu">
                    @foreach(var sub in myView.Childs)
                    {
                        <li><a href="#@(sub.Name)">@sub.Name</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
                @foreach(var sub in myView.Childs)
                {
                    <div id="@sub.Name">
                     // Content goes here
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            //Content for else
        }
    }
</div>
```

So in jQuery

```
$("#mainView").tabs();
```

works just fine. But when I do

```
$("#mainView .subView").tabs();
```

It gives me an error "jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier". I checked the resulting HTML and it does not have any errors. I do not know if we can create tabs like this or not. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#mainView > .subView").tabs();
```

Hopefully it works...!

Comment: Nope.. still the same error. also tried $("#mainView div.subView")

Comment: $("#mainView > .subView > .subMenu").tabs();